# HttpURLConnection to upload to a php script (insert query)

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload data into my mysql database.

The code below doesn't throw any errors, but when I check the database, the data isn't there.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? It doesnt even seem to run the php.

I have a feeling it is a problem with the php code. It used to work with httppost, but recently, the data started to get mixed up, and it would hang. I saw that httppost is depreciated, so am trying to use HttpURLConnection instead.

Here is the java:

```
public void uploadmydata() throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.myurl.co.uk/test5.php");
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Joe"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surname", "Bloggs"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "UK"));


    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getQuery(params));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    urlConnection.connect();


}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

and here is my php:

```
 session_start();


 //CREATE CONNECTION
$con=mysql_connect("00.00.00.00","my_username","password") or die          (mysql_error());

 //CHECK CONNECTION
 if (!$con) { die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
 } 

else
//echo 'connected!';

 //SELECT SITE DATABASE

mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);


$name=$_POST['name'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$country=$_POST['country'];


//sql query

mysql_query("insert into myTable (name, surname, country)       values('{$name}','{$surname}','{$country}')");

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Have you looked in the PHP error log?  If the problem is with that code and you enable logging it will even tell you the error and even what line it was on.  Also... probably time to rewrite it to use [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: And the server access log might tell you if your Java was actually POSTing to the site ...

Comment: oh dear - more stuff to learn. The raw access log was last updated hours ago, although I just tried the upload

Comment: Besides that, don't use the mysql_ functions in PHP, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks I will switch to PDO, but would like to get it running first